# Python - Fill in form on website when Outlook appointment is created

Tags: python, outlook

I am looking for a way to automate the below scenario for free. I considered Zapier but the webhook is a premium feature (=not free)

Is the following scenario possible by using Python?
If so, can you please advise how to get started and what I would need to make it happen as a beginner?

**Scenario/requirements:**

1. User creates an appointment manually in the Microsoft Outlook calender.
2. The user gives it a color categorisation (e.g. green = administration work ; red = driving time)
3. Whenever an appointment has received a color code in Outlook, it should register the worktime on a custom web application. The following information needs to be entered in a form on that website:

- the start time (date + hour) of the outlook calender appointment
- the end time (date + hour) of the outlook calender appointment
- the subject (=title) of the outlook calender appointment
- the definition of the category (=color) of the outlook calender appointment

4. extra requirement (nice to have) if a color changes, it should update it in the custom web application.

All help is welcome
Many thanks
Regards
Yanni

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a subject for an Outlook add-in where you could subscribe to the `PropertyChange` event of Outlook items. The event is fired when an explicit built-in property (for example, `Subject`) of the object is changed. See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) to get started quickly.

Python is not supported by VSTO, so your choice is C# or VB.NET. But Python can be used for automating Outlook if required.